Stop Windows 11 from waking when plugging in/out
So I just bought a new asus vivobook and I noticed an issue, that it is perfectly fine if I close the lid to put it to sleep (either plugged in or out) , but whenever there is an event of either plugging in the charger or out it wakes from sleep (even when the lid is still closed) and continues being idle with fan on thus heating and draining battery for hours.
I have done the following this but no success yet

Update power setting in control panel to put sleep when lid closed in both ac, dc
disable wake timers in ac, dc (also checked powerconfig -waketimers)
can't find any option of Do not wake when A/C in asus uefi firmware settings (as I read in another answer somewhere)

And I know hibernation will do the job, I have configured it to hibernate after 30 mins of inactivity BUT it's not the solution I'm looking for (1 - I want the default uninterrupted sleep behaviour, 2 - as it wakes from sleep idk why it goes in a loop of sleep for 30 seconds and wake for 2 sec repeatedly which prevents it from hibernating or sleeping again as well and I think is the main cause of heating, I found about this trend in powercfg/sleepstudy and reason for the wake call is given mouse activity but I don't have any bluetooth mouse or keyboard)
PS - windows 11

They problem you're experiencing has been one of my banes for a long time. I'm surprised more people aren't upset about these things! I also have a problem where my computers will randomly wake up - then never go back to sleep.
After alot of research, I'm beginning to suspect the issue is related to Windows' implementation of modern standby in conflict with certain computer vendors custom firmware/bios configuration. Hopefully someone has some answers...

Stage one of resolving this is always going to be: Check for and install any and all updates for BIOS and other firmware, Drivers, and OS patches. Do this and then report back. Second, wake events should be logged in the event viewer. Review these to find the reason Windows thinks it is waking up.

@DavidShader yeah, I also read about the shitty modern standby, but i am not willing to take the risk of modifying registry as posed in some solutions (atleast before trying everything else) and also just to list out here some people got it solved by reinstalling the ac power adapter from device manager

@music2myear everything is up-to-date and I couldnt find anything in the event viewer, particularly in the power troubleshooter filter, can you guide me where exactly to look in event viewer or possibly link to some related answer
